# how to detach internal hdd with windows and its boot loader during ubuntu 16.04.1 installation on external hdd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

**Like in the topic, is there any way to detach internal hdd with windows and its boot loader (from terminal) during ubuntu 16.04.1 installation on external hdd?**

Each time when I try to install Ubuntu on my external driver, windows boot loader is messed up. I don't want it to happen. I know that i can make boot-able usb device without the need of installing grub in place of windows boot loader.

Also what do i need to do to install ubuntu on my external HDD in (u)efi mode, because even with "legacy boot" option enabled in my (u)efi setup, I can't see any not (u)efi device in my boot loader.

External and internal hdd`s are GPT

Comment: i beg for a help... I am trying to install ubuntu purely on external hdd for a weak now...

Comment: I have installed many times to external flash drives & sdb. The only issues is that grub only installs to ESP - efi system partition on sda. That should not interfere with Windows but then requires you to copy /EFI/ubuntu folder from sda to external & copy again to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi as external devices with UEFI only boot with bootx64.efi. Make sure you have ESP on external:http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu and then install & copy files.https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338836 Then UUID update fstab.